# Effects of measurement on the entropy in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, quantum-information, quantum-measurements, statistical-mechanics

How does measurement in quantum mechanics (QM) impact the system's entropy? The measurement process in QM is considered time-irreversible. Are there principles akin to the second law of thermodynamics governing the entropy of the system during irreversible or spontaneous processes?

Comment: depends on what you exactly you mean. Measurements, in general, don't necessarily come with a post-measurement state. When they do, projective measurement will generally result in pure states, ie zero entropy of the post-measurement states. Unless you mean something else here with "the system's entropy". If you're asking about the classical entropy of the measurement outcome probabilities, that's a different question, tightly related to majorization results, among other things. For example if $\rho_{AB}$ is entangled then $\rho_A$ has larger entropy than $\rho_{AB}$

Answer (score 1):

A measurement is a physical process that produces a record of a physical quantity. In both classical and quantum physics such processes are reversible according to the equations of motion. In quantum physics reversing a measurement requires reversing the creation of the record for all of the copies of the information. In most real world cases this is impossible because it would require controlling the motion of air molecules and photons in the environment.

Quantum measurements increase the von Neumann entropy of the measurement device and the measured system. So quantum measurements that are irreversible produce an irreversible increase in entropy.

For more details, see:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.08598